# Cyclical Argument in Plato's Phaedo

Tags: metaphysics

Can anybody tell me in simple words the major objections to the Cyclical Argument in Plato's Phaedo ?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Not_Here. It might be but I'm not sure and am giving the OP the benefit of the doubt. This is a difficult bit of the Phaedo, which anyone might have problems with. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas That's fine, but is immaterial to whether or not we should ask. It is a rule of the site that homework questions need to be explicit, not that they are banned.

Comment: Birth and death balance out since we see neither explosion of life nor everything dying out. Therefore, everything that dies must be reborn. That is the [cyclical argument](https://www.iep.utm.edu/phaedo/). Why something *else* can not be born to replace what died is unclear. Socrates tries to address this with his further recollection argument about the knowledge of ideas that the soul must have acquired before the birth. Alas, that does not work either - even if the soul pre-existed in the ideal realm it does not follow that it must have gotten there after a death in the sensible world.

Comment: @Not_Here. Point taken but if the question is not homework there's no need to say that it is not. And unless one has good grounds for thinking it is homework, why ask? Some questions are pretty clearly homework. I couldn't see grounds for thinking the question was or might be. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas Sure, I also agree with you that we should have a reason for thinking so. My grounds for thinking that it is a homework question are that it is a very short but specific question. There is no background explanation like "I was reading Phaedo and I got confused at this specific part" or "Plato's argument doesn't really convince me and I'm wondering what others have thought" or anything like that; it's a single sentence with no other details about what is going on. The question is very specific and is very direct and and could have easily been lifted from a homework assignment.

Comment: @Not_Here. Thank you for your v. carefully considered and substantial reply. I now recognise the cogency of your reasons for suspecting that this was a homework question. I will bear in mind the considerations you bring up. They will certainly help me from now on. I appreciate. Best - Geoffrey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following extract from Michael Pakaluk might help though it will probably need more than one reading (just speaking from experience) :

> The Cyclical Argument (CA) is not unfairly presented as follows:
>
> 1. Anything that comes to take on an attribute which has an opposite,
>      previously had that opposite attribute.
> 2. Being dead and being alive are opposite attributes.
> 3. When something comes to be alive, it comes to take on the attribute
>      of being alive.
> 4. Therefore, anything that comes to be alive previously had the attribute
>      of being dead.
> 5. But everything that is dead was previously alive.
> 6. Therefore, anything that comes to be alive was previously alive.
> 7. Therefore, living things come from previously living things.
> 8. Therefore, living things will once again become living things.
> 9. Nothing comes to take on again, at a later time, an attribute that it
>      now has, if it perishes in the process.
> 10. Thus, living things do not perish when they come to be dead, and in
>       this sense they are immortal.
>
> Plato's strategy is to connect this present life of a living thing with a previous life; that done, he draws the general conclusion that living things
>    were previously alive; yet, he reasons, they could not have come alive
>    again, if they did not endure in the interval between their previous life
>    and their current one; and thus, as regards any living thing, we can have
>    some confidence that it will continue to endure, in the interval after this
>    current life and before its next life.
>
> Thus stated, the argument is clearly unsound, because the first premise
>    is in need of two familiar qualifications. That 'opposites come from opposites' is true only if: (i) we presume that we are not dealing with a case
>    of simple generation, where something comes to be F only in coming to
>    be simpliciter; and (ii) the opposites are 'contradictory', rather than mere
>    'contrary' opposites. But if premise 1. is qualified accordingly, premise 2.
>    needs to be revised: being dead and being alive are not contradictory
>    opposites, since there are things that are neither dead nor afive. Yet if we
>    rewrite premise 2., so that it involves opposites that are properly contradictory, e.g. 'Being not alive and being alive are opposite attributes', then
>    premise 5. needs to be changed accordingly, becoming: 'Everything that
>    is not alive was previously alive' - which is evidently false.
>
> It would be good to have a diagnosis of why the argument goes wrong,
>    and for this purpose Gallop's commentary is particularly useful. Gallop
>    correctly notes, for instance, that Plato in CA tends to speak as though it
>    is the soul which comes to be alive, rather than the animal, but - Gallop
>    objects - this "insinuates a view of 'birth' in which the soul's discarnate
>    existence is already covertly assumed. And since that is precisely what
>    the argument purports to prove, the very conception of incarnation can be
>    seen to beg the essential question" (105). Again, Gallop wonders why we
>    shouldn't understand 'being dead' (in our premise 2. above) to mean, simply, 'ceasing to exist', in which case, clearly, 'being alive' and 'being
>    dead' could not be treated as opposing predicates, as CA requires, since
>    one would, in that case, be treating existence as though it were a predicate. Speculating on why Plato might have resisted this identification, Gallop
>    remarks that "a wedge might be driven between 'being dead' and 'ceasing to exist' by treating Socrates' soul as a separate subject, distinct from
>    Socrates himself, and alternating between incarnate and discarmate states.
>    But this would be, once again, to assume what has to be proved" (106).
>    Again, objecting to (our) premise 3. above, Gallop remarks that "The
>    sense of 'coming to be alive' required for the argument is not that in
>   which a living thing comes into being, but that in which a soul 'becomes
>    incarnate' in a living body. Yet it cannot do this unless it already exists
>    before birth or conception. And whether it does so or not is just what is
>    at issue" (110).
>
> So Gallop maintains that CA goes awry because Plato begs the question, surreptitiously supposing that the soul is a distinct subject, independent of the body.

## References

Michael Pakaluk, 'Degrees of Separation in the "Phaedo"',  Phronesis, Vol. 48, No. 2 (2003), pp. 89-115: 90-2.

D. Gallop, Plato: Phaedo, Oxford: Clarendon Press, 1975.

C.J.F. Williams, 'On Dying', Philosophy 1969 (44) 217-30.